# AndroidStudio: Why does LayoutInflater switch back to old activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I've been looking for similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but with no luck. I have my first activity, MapsActivity. I want my second activity, AboutActivity, to appear in the FrameLayout of the MapsActivity layout, so I used LayoutInflater. When I run the app, I see my AboutActivity for about half a second, then it quickly changes back to the MapActivity. I don't have any errors on logcat and both activities are listed in the Manifest file.

Here is my MapsActivity (with just the relevant parts). My Google Map is inside the fragment (where I hope my second activity will appear). I have a menu button, and one of the buttons leads to the second activity.:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private String[] menuOptions;
private DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout;
private ListView myList;
//    private Fragment menuFragment;
private MapFragment mMapFragment;

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (findViewById(R.id.content_frame)!=null){
        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
            return;
        }
        // to add fragment dynamically, create new instance- add to frame layout
        mMapFragment= MapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, mMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        //make menu from array indices
        menuOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
        myDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        myList= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        //adapter for list view
        myList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuOptions));
        //list's click listener
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        Button menuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                myDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });

...
 private void selectItem(int position){
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            //Highlight selected item
            myList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(myList);
            break;
        case 1:
            //about
            Intent switchIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(switchIntent);
            break;
```

Here is my AboutActivity, the second activity. The activity_about only appears for one second. I want it to appear where the map was.

```
public class AboutActivity extends MapsActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_about, frame);
}
```

Here is my activity_maps.xml, it features a map and a FrameLayout where I want my other activities to appear (this way I can also have the ListView menu in each activity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Menu" />
    </FrameLayout>

        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111">
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: " I want my second activity, AboutActivity, to appear in the FrameLayout of the MapsActivity layout, so I used LayoutInflater."   why?

Comment: @EliasFazel I wanted my FrameLayout to contain my map, and later my second activity. I thought that LayoutInflater would be the be the best way to programatically change from my map to my second activity. Would you have done it a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `Button` and `ListView` in both activities, why not use `AboutFragment` instead of `AboutActivity`. And when you click the aboutButton in ListView, just replace the fragment shows in the `FrameLayout`.You have to let you `menuButton` outside the FrameLayout.

**activity_xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/menuButton"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Menu" />
    </LinearLayout>


        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111">
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

public class AboutActivity extends **FragmentActivity**, and try to use fragments.

In "main" layout create one:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Menu" />
</FrameLayout>
```

in mainActivity inflate your fragment created into frameLayout.

Comment: extending FragmentActivity does not seem to work, because I need the button and listview from the MapsActivity to also be in my AboutActivity. I'm not sure if I understand your code but I do also need the ListView to be added to the xml file.